# Travel the checkerboard from top left to bottom right with lowest cost

Tags: algorithm

There is a checkerboard with m rows and n columns. And in each checker, there is a integer representing the cost to pass through this checker. Now I should find a path with lowest cost from top left checker to the bottom right checker.

**INPUT**
In the first line there are two integers m and n representing the number of rows and columns. And in the following m lines, there are n integers in each line representing the cost to pass through each checker.

**OUTPUT**
A single line containing an integer representing the lowest cost.

**SAMPLE INPUT**

```
4 5
 1  100  1   1  1
 1  100  1  100 1
 1   1   1  100 1
100 100 100 100 1
```

**SAMPLE OUTPUT**

```
12
```

I tried to solve this problem with dynamic programming. It will be easy if each step could only be downward or rightward. But I don't know how to do  while a checker could be reached from all four directions. Could anyone tell me what strategy I should use?

Comment: can you explain how result is getting 12

Comment: can you have negative cost ?

Comment: @smn_onrocks you choose all the 1s (start,down,down,right,right,right,up,up,right,right,right,down,down,down)

Comment: @Amir All costs are positive integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following algorithm can be used provided that every cost is `>= 0`

```
create an 'output' array the same size as the 'cost' array
set all entries in the 'output' array to 'unknown'
the first entry in the 'output' array equals the first entry of the 'cost' array
write the coordinates of the first entry {0,0} to a queue
while the queue is not empty
{
    read a set of coordinates from the queue
    for each neighboring square
    {
        compute the cost to move from the current square to the neighbor
        if ( the current cost of the neighbor is unknown or higher )
        { 
            set the cost of the neighboring square to the new lower cost
            add the coordinates of the neighboring square to the queue
        }
    }
}
```

Once the queue is empty, the output array will have the lowest cost to travel to each square. The image below shows how the algorithm works with the cost array given in the question. The green squares are squares that were modified in each pass of the algorithm.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**If the costs can not be negative**, it's a very simple question:

1. Create a graph. A node represents a checker. An edge exists if two checker are neighbour.
2. Assign the cost of each checker, to the cost of all the edges which goes **into** the corresponding node of the checker.
3. Use a standard [Dijkstra Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) to find the shortest path from the start node to the target, with a time complexity of [image].

**Otherwise if the costs can be any integer**, it would be a little complicated. You might wanna replace the third step with [Bellman-Ford Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm) to solve this question. Then the worst time complexity would be [image].

Comment: I'm afraid this algorithm would result in Time Limit Exceeded. Anyway I will give a try. Thx

Comment: It wouldn't if it's just an ICPC-level question.